# Show that for $n_1,n_2,...,n_p$ natural numbers, there is a natural number $n$ such that $\varphi(n)=n_1!n_2!...n_p!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, totient-function

Show that for $n_1,n_2,...,n_p$ natural numbers, there is a natural number $n$ such that $\varphi(n)=n_1!n_2!...n_p!$. In the proof, they order the numbers such that $n_1\leq n_2 ...\leq n_p$. Let $p_1,p_2,...,p_m$ prime numbers smaller or equal to $n_p$. They are the sole prime numbers in decomposing $N=n_1!n_2!...n_p!$. I don't understand why they say that, if $p_i\leq n_j$, then every $p_i$ is a factor of $n_j!$ and why $(p_i-1)$ divides $N$, such that $N=(p_1-1)(p_2-1)...(p_m-1)p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}...p_m^{k_m}$ and then $p_1-1,p_2-1,...,p_m-1$ can be further decomposed using this factors and so $N=\varphi(n)$, where$n=p_1^{k_1+1}p_2^{k_2+1}...p_m^{k_m+1}$.[image]

Comment: The last part is strange. "further decomposed" is in particular confusing. Moreover, that each $p_i-1$ divives $N$ does not mean that the product divides $N$.

Comment: It's exactly what is on the answer sheet.

Comment: Clear is that $p_i$ divides $n_j!$ , when $p_i\le n_j$ (but $p_i$ need not divide $n_j$)

Comment: I doubt very much that it is "exactly what is on the answer sheet." You haven't quoted any text directly, you have given your own paraphrased version. Can we have it word for word?

Comment: @TonyK OK. I'll introduce a photo in the post. It's from ,,Matematica de excelenta", Paralela 45, 2016. The language is Romanian.

Comment: Nu vorbesc limba română...

Comment: I don't have the possibility to translate it in another way than it was posed in the question, because it is the way I think it translates from Romanian, and there is no English edition, unfortunately. Please, try to translate it if my english version, posted here, is not satisfactory.

Comment: What exactly are you not understanding? As @Peter pointed out, if $p_i\leq n_j$ then $p_i\mid n_j!$, and not necessarily $n_j$ as you wrote in your question. The the argument seems clear to me. Is there something else you don't understand?

Comment: @AlessioDV Why $(p_i-1)$ divides $N$ and the rest.

Comment: Because if $p_i \mid n_j!$ (do not forget the factorial), then $(p_i-1)\mid n_j!$ and thus it divides $N$.